# Why options aren't showing? (jqueryui-autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, materialize, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to build an autocomplete with a loading screen.

Technologies used : Materialize (1.0.0-rc.2), jQueryUi AutoComplete (1.11.4).

It works properly but not with a "home made" loading popup.

I've made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n4o8L5dy/3/) to show an example. Enter characters in the input and you'll see the bug (loading popup open correctly but options won't show up). If you want to see it working, comment the indicated lines).

The autocomplete is initialized this way (setTimeout to emulate an ajax call):

```
var autocompletion = $("#autocompl").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    Wait.show(function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        var elementsFilter = availableTags.filter(tag => tag.toUpperCase().includes(request.term.toUpperCase()));
        response(elementsFilter);
        Wait.remove();
      }, 1000)
    });
  },
}).autocomplete('instance');
```

The loading popup is a very basic home made "plugin" with two functions `show` and `remove`

```
var Wait = (function() {
  var instanceModal = null;

  return {
    show: function(callback, options) {
      if (!instanceModal) {
        $('#modalePatientez').modal({
          dismissible: false
        });
        instanceModal = M.Modal.getInstance($('#modalePatientez'));
      }
      instanceModal.options.onOpenEnd = function() {
        callback();
      };
      instanceModal.open();

    },

    remove: function(callback) {
      if (callback) {
        instanceModal.options.onCloseEnd = callback;
      }
      instanceModal.close();
    }
  }
})();
```

I tried to debug by hand and with `console.log` : functions are executed correctly (in the correct order).

Do you know why `options` aren't shown when the loading popup is "enabled" ?

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of the issue is input type looses the focus as soon as the pop-up opens. Because of that JQuery UI cancels the whole autocomplete execution and we don't see the expected behavior. Solution to this is preventing blur event (preventing particular input from loosing focus). Following code will solve your problem:

```
$("#autocompl").change(function(e){
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  $(this).off("blur");
});
```

[working jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/3jcu16ny/)

Comment: Thank you! From what you've suggested, I wrote a workaround that is going to work for any autocomplete input : 
    $(document).on("blur", ".ui-autocomplete-input", function(event) {
          event.stopImmediatePropagation();
               $(this).off("blur");
       });

Comment: After few days, I realize, it can't be accepted as a solution. When the user leaves the input it should close the input. But with this workaround it won't happen. I'm searching a solution to "remove" the focus when a modal is open (which is, as you mention it, the root cause of the issue)

Comment: Agreed from user prospective it should lose focus when pop-up is opened. But JQurey UI auto-suggest does not work in that way. When I posted this answer I debugged JqueryUi plugin to come to the conclusion. Need to find other alternative way :)